# Solve the equation, hat consists on an arithmetical progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{99}=0.$$

I said to prove with $0+1+2+3+\cdots+99=0$. How should I proceed?

Comment: For any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N$ : $$1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$

Comment: $0+1+2+3+...+99=0$ ??...

Comment: $1+x+\cdots+x^{99}=\frac{x^{100}-1}{x-1}=0\iff \begin{cases}x^{100}=1\\x\neq 1\end{cases}\iff x=-1$ (if $x\in\mathbb R$).

Answer (score 3):

$1+x+\cdots+x^{99}=\frac{x^{100}-1}{x-1}=0\iff \begin{cases}x^{100}=1\\x\neq 1\end{cases}\iff x=-1$ (if $x\in\mathbb R$).

This uses the well-known [geometric progression formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression):
$$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{m-1}=\frac{a(r^m-1)}{r-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

another observation $$1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{99}=\\(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{98})+(x+x^3+x^5+...+x^{99})=0\\(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{98})+x(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{98})=\\(1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{98})(1+x)=0\\\rightarrow (1+x)=0 \rightarrow x=-1$$note that ! $$1+x^2+x^4+...+x^{98} \neq 0\\$$

Comment: What if $x=i$, the imaginary number?